# C library function exit() with SLURM on cluster

Tags: c, cluster-computing, slurm

I'm having a problem with the simple usage of exit().

The **context** is running a program on a cluster for parallel computing, so we have a Slurm system installed managing and watching over all processes.
The **problem**  is now that, when calling `exit(1)` in my program, SLURM doesn't seem to register that and the CPUs stay busy, burning up my allocated CPU-hours uselessly, although the program has already terminated.

So my **question** is:
 What does `exit()` do differently compared to a regular `return 1` in `main()`?
Is there a simple way to fix my exit signal?

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour of SLURM is to allow processes in a job to complete, even if one process crashes or exits with a non-zero exit code. You can change this by setting `KillOnBadExit=1` in your slurm.conf, or using either `-K/--kill-on-bad-exit=1` with `srun`.

Comment: As mpirun/mpiexec are derivatives of srun, I guess then this should work as well with them? I'll tryout and report back, thank you.